# How to send an error status code like Bad Request (400) from a google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-status-codes

This is a `doPost` function inside a Google App that returns a **Hello World** message.

```
function doPost(e){

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello World');
}
```

Now suppose I want to only accept valid JSON to be posted to this Google App endpoint and I want to send a respones with Bad Request status. How can I do that. Here's the pseudo code:

```
function doPost(e){
  try{
     const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
     return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello World');
  }catch(err){
      // Send Bad Request
  }      

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, `ContentService` cannot modify the status code. It seems that this is the current specification. So in your situation, how about returning the error message like `ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({error: 'Error message'}));`? And, when you return the valid value, for example, how about `ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({value: 'value'}));`? By this, you can check the value using the key of JSON data. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike that's what I'm already doing. But it's just an ugly hack.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `that's what I'm already doing. But it's just an ugly hack.`, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike BTW, it probably is helpful for others who look into this (and Thanks!). I suggest you post it as an answer. Do you have a reference for current specification of this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, I cannot find about the method for modifying the status code in Class ContentService. So as the current comment, such method is not included in Class ContentService. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) I would like to prepare an answer by including this.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If you have any modification points, please tell me.

Comment: Looks like this is still the case with the `ContentService` class - as @Tanaike mentioned, it doesn't look like you can set an http status code that a client app could catch. I posted another idea for a workaround below, based on returning a function body via `ContentService.createTextOutput()`. The client can then run a dynamic function that either throws an error on the client side, or returns legitimate JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `ContentService` cannot modify the status code. When I saw the official document of Class ContentService, such method cannot be found. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) It seems that this is the current specification.

So in your situation, as the current workaround, how about returning the value as JSON data? By this, you can check the value using the key of JSON data. For example, how about the following sample script?

- When the correct value without the error is returned,

  ```
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({value: 'value'}));
  ```
- When the value with the error is returned,

  ```
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({error: 'Error message'}));
  ```
- When you need `.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)`, please add this.

#### Note:

- When I searched about this at the Google issue tracker, I couldn't find it. So how about reporting this as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### Reference:

- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround that allows raising errors on the client side for errors on the web app side. For example, a client might need to catch errors such as bad url args sent to the web app (i.e. the OP's question), or catch errors thrown by a method that is called from `doGet()` or `doPost()`.

As far as I know, when an error is thrown downstream of `doGet()` or `doPost()`, a text error message is returned in the response, but the web app request itself succeeds, so there is no error thrown on the client side. As @Tanaike said, there still seems no way for a Google web app dev to throw an HTTP error from the app (like `400 Bad Request` or `500 Internal Server Error`).

The idea involves returning a function body from the web app, which the client can use to create and run a dynamic function via the `Function()` constructor (this assumes Javascript is available on the client).

So the web app can be written to:

- return a function body that will throw an error for bad args, server method errors, etc.
- return a function body that will return intended JSON when there is no error

This is a bit of a hack, but it unifies error handling on the client side. The client makes the http request, constructs a function using the function body returned in the response, and then runs this function, all in one `try{}` block. Then both Google-raised http errors and web app downstream errors can be caught in the `catch{}` block.

Example setup for a Google Apps Script client making a request to a Google web app:

(1) In the web app `doGet()` or `doPost()` function:

```
// this string will be returned by the webapp
var fnBody;

// for bad url args, return a fnBody that will throw an error with an indicative message 
if(!urlArgsOk()) {
  fnBody =  "'use strict'; throw new Error('POST args error');";  
} 
// if url args are ok, call server method
else {
    try {
      // if the method call succeeds, return a fnBody that will return the intended JSON
      var returnObj = myServerMethod(methodArgs);
      fnBody = "'use strict'; return JSON.stringify(" + JSON.stringify(returnObj) + ");";
    }
    catch(serverErr) {
      // if the method call fails, return a fnBody that will throw an error ...
      // ... simple example shown here, but info from serverErr can be included in fnBody
      fnBody =  "'use strict'; throw new Error('server error');";  
    } 
}    

// return fnBody, which can be run via Function() on the client
return ContentService.createTextOutput(fnBody).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

(2) On the client side (Google apps script client making a POST request)

```
// Set the url, payload, and fetch options
var url = "https://script.google.com/_______/exec?arg1=val1&arg2=val2";
var payload = getPayloadString(); // whatever POST payload needs to be sent

var options = {
  'method' : 'POST',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'muteHttpExceptions': false, // let Google http exceptions come through
  'payload' : payload,
  'headers': {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
};

// Send a request to the web app
try {

  // make the POST request - this throws Google-generated HTTP errors if any
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  // create the dynamic function from the fnBody returned
  var responseFn = new Function(response.getContentText());
  
  // run the function - this returns intended JSON content
  // or throws web app downstream errors if any
  var responseJson = responseFn();

}
catch(err) {
   // handle either source of error
   console.log(err.message);
}
```

There are potential security risks associated with dynamic code, so I'm not sure how widely applicable this might be. I might use this in an aplication that lives entirely in a private GCP domain, i.e. with the web app restricted to same-domain users and the client app also in the same domain. Some security is also added by the `'use strict'` directive, which boxes the dynamic function in by setting its `this` to `undefined` [(ref)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#changes_in_strict_mode). But it's still a good idea to think through the dynamic code implications [(ref1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function), [ref2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).