# Custom error message in Google Apps Script Error object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling

I have an Apps Script webapp that throws a custom error message.

**Apps Script**

```
try{
  // Do stuff
}
catch (e){
  throw new Error('foo');
}
```

It works all right when executing it in a browser, displaying, as it should:

> Error: foo (line 126, file "Code")

However, when I try to catch this error message using an ajax call, I can't get the message.

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
  url: scriptUrl,
  success: function(data){
    // Do stuff
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error); // Logs object
    console.log(error.message); // Logs undefined
    console.log(error.statusText); // Logs 'error'
  }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66350288/7108653

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I flagged your question as the duplicate.